# Almost skew polynomial ring an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Is the following ring in integral domain?

Since Ore extensions of domains are Ore extensions, this question can be reformulated as follows: Since the relation look *almost* like those of a skew polynomial ring, can this ring in fact be written as a skew polynomial ring?

Consider the $k$-algebra $R=k\langle x_i, c_i\rangle_{i=1,\ldots,n}$, $k$ not of characteristic 2,
subject to the following relations:

- $x_ix_j = x_jx_i$ for all $i, j$
- $x_ic_i = -c_i x_i$
- $x_ic_j = c_j x_i$ for all $i\neq j$
- $c_ic_j = -c_j c_i$ for all $i\neq j$

I haven't found a counterexample yet.

Comment: I think, skew-polynomial rings are an integral domain.

Comment: If $k$ has characteristic two you have an UFD, yes... :)

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, I just read that Ore extensions of domains are domains. However, is this really a skew polynomial ring? When multiplying, I do not always act with the automorphism $-1$, but only for certain pairs of $x$ and $c$.

Comment: @Bubaya What definition of UFD are you using? There isn't a widely used noncommutative version AFAIK. Are you using [P. M. Cohn's definitions](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1963-109-02/S0002-9947-1963-0155851-X/S0002-9947-1963-0155851-X.pdf)?

Comment: @rschwieb I have to admit that I did not think about this properly. Since I realized that for what I want to do domain is sufficient, I reformulated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, @DietrichBurde's comment turned out to be helpful: Just start with $\mathbf C[x_i]$, take the automorphism $\sigma_1: x_1\mapsto -x_1$ that leaves all other $x_i$ unchanged. Then we can form the skew polynomial ring $\mathbf C[x_i, c_1]$ such that $x_1c_1 = -c_1x_1$. Continue inductively. Hence the ring is a skew polynomial ring and hence remains a domain.